# How can I do LEFT_JOIN in ComponentType with CriteriaQuery API

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have the following mappings:

ProductProviderDetail.class

```
@Entity
@Table
public class ProductProviderDetail {
    // other fields
    @Embedded
    private AuditInformation auditInformation;
    // getters and setters
}
```

AuditInformation.class

```
@Embeddable
public class AuditInformation  {
    // other fields
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = true) // default is true but I want to make a point here
    @JoinColumn(name = "head", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Head head;
    // getters and setters
}
```

As you can see there's an association inside of a `ComponentType` such that it's `optional`.
Querying this property would look like

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Tuple> query = builder.createTupleQuery();
Root<ProductProviderDetail > root = query.from(ProductProviderDetail .class);
    
query.multiselect(root.get("auditInformation").get("head"));
```

Since the association is optional, I'd like to make a LEFT_JOIN which, in this case, would be something like

```
root.get("auditInformation").join("head", JoinType.LEFT);
```

The thing is `root.get("auditInformation")` would return an instance of `SingularAttributePath` which is not capable of doing a `.join()` operation.
Is there any other ways that I can achieve this type of query with CriteriaQuery API? Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution after browsing the site. Apparently, we're supposed to do `.join()` on both the component and attribute level. Like so.

```
root.join("auditInformation").join("head", JoinType.LEFT);
```